# Getting error while trying to run th keytool for app signing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

here is the error i get in my cmd when i try to run keytool command.

```
Illegal option:  10\upload-keystore.jks
keytool -genkeypair [OPTION]...

Generates a key pair

Options:

 -alias <alias>          alias name of the entry to process
 -keyalg <alg>           key algorithm name
 -keysize <size>         key bit size
 -groupname <name>       Group name. For example, an Elliptic Curve name.
 -sigalg <alg>           signature algorithm name
 -dname <name>           distinguished name
 -startdate <date>       certificate validity start date/time
 -ext <value>            X.509 extension
 -validity <days>        validity number of days
 -keypass <arg>          key password
 -keystore <keystore>    keystore name
 -signer <alias>         signer alias
 -signerkeypass <arg>    signer key password
 -storepass <arg>        keystore password
 -storetype <type>       keystore type
 -providername <name>    provider name
 -addprovider <name>     add security provider by name (e.g. SunPKCS11)
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -addprovider
 -providerclass <class>  add security provider by fully-qualified class name
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -providerclass
 -providerpath <list>    provider classpath
 -v                      verbose output
 -protected              password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -?, -h, or --help" for this help message
```

I hane tried the original cmmand shown in official website of pub releasing document from windows but i always getting error .can you please help me make signing.

Answer (score 0):

There is one another way to generate key go to your flutter android folder using terminal and type **./gradlew signingReport** for linux or **gradlew signingReport** for vs code or android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using Windows for  building app then use android studio and built in jdk. It will Make it so much simple to build the app bundle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).